# How to store field value of the document in firestore

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

**Strong text**

i am trying to store the field value of the document in fire store. my Firestore database path like is :
samyata(collection)-> uid's(document)->wallet( sub collection)->again registered users uid's(sub document). In sub document the fields are amount,bank account number, usd. generally the values for the fields are "zero". whenever user add some money to the wallet that added money will be store in the usd field. so i give the database path like is:

```
db.collection("samyata")
    .document(mAuth.getuid.toString())
    .collection("wallet")
    .document(mAuth.getuid.toString())
    .setData(dataToSave);
```

But it display this error "java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.String.toString()' on a null object reference". please help how to solve that problem. I want to store the field value in document in firestore. My firestore statement is correct or not? how to reach that path to store the particular field value in the document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your database looks like you say then setting the value in that way is correct. The problem in your code is this:

```
mAuth.getuid.toString()
```

That error says that you are trying to use `toString()` method on a null object reference. This means that `mAuth.getuid` return `null`. To solve this, you need to verify your authentication process. Be sure that `mAuth.getuid` returns the correct uid and your problem will be solved.

Comment: Thank for reply. i solved the problem. What you said is correct. After posting my question I got the idea and solved that one.

Comment: Is there everything alright? Can i help you with other informations?